# Python regex not matching but works on regex tester

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

```
import re as regex
pattern = regex.compile(r'\w[\w\/\\-]*(\s*[\w\/\\-])*')
print pattern.findall("HELLO-WORLD")
```

This just prints out `['']`

The regex works correctly on an online regex tester. Why is it not matching?

Comment: If I would put my regex \w[\w\/\\-]*(\s*[\w\/\\-])* on https://regex101.com/ it works fine and matches HELLO-WORLD as expected.

Comment: Try `\w[\w/\\-]*(?:\s*[\w/\\-])*`. See http://ideone.com/NIarL0

Comment: @alexis: There is no lookahead in my suggested pattern, please see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  use a *non-capturing* group (i.e. `(?:\s*[\w/\\-])`, the `(?:...)` does not form a capturing group and `re.findall` returns the whole match, not the captured group value(s)):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\w[\w/\\-]*(?:\s*[\w/\\-])*')
print(pattern.findall("HELLO-WORLD"))
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/NIarL0)

Also, note that `/` symbol does not have to be escaped in a Python regex pattern.

Another point is that there is a PyPi regex module, and that is why I suggest using `import re` rather than hiding it with `as regex`.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Explanation: if `re.findall` contains capturing groups, it will _only_ return the content captured by the groups; not the whole match.

Comment: Yes, here is the relevant link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall